# ggplot2 - trouble with legend when using geom_point() in (R)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create a `ggplot` with two `geom_line()`s and two `geom_point()`s, all coming from the same dataset (which I've got as a `data.table` currently). The data look like this:

```
> head(data)
        month     high_q     low_q
1: 2009-03-01 0.04894481 0.1462436
2: 2009-04-01 0.04910757 0.1452902
3: 2009-06-01 0.04871459 0.1471519
4: 2009-07-01 0.04938127 0.1489580
5: 2009-08-01 0.04899900 0.1481020
6: 2009-09-01 0.04888317 0.1479808
```

I would like `high_q` and `low_q` plotted against `month`, both as `geom_line()`s and `geom_point()`s. So far, I've got this:

[image]

Which is generated using:

```
require('ggplot2')    

plot <- ggplot() +
geom_line(data = data, 
  aes(x = month, 
      y = high_q),
  size = 0.15,
  color = 'gray40') +
geom_point(data = data,
  aes(x = month,
      y = high_q,
      color = 'HQ'),
  shape = 0,
  size = 1.2) +
geom_line(data = data, 
  aes(x = month, 
      y = low_q),
  size = 0.15,
  color = 'gray40')  +
geom_point(data = data,
  aes(x = month,
      y = low_q,
      color = 'LQ'),
  shape = 2,
  size = 1.2) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("skyblue4", "skyblue4")) +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = '#CCCCCC'),
      panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = '#CCCCCC'),
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 5),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
      legend.title = element_blank(),
      legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm")) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.02),
                   limits = c(0.04, 0.16))
```

For my purposes, everything is turning out exactly how I'd like it to except for one small issue: the legend entries for `'HQ'` and `'LQ'` both have the triangle shape and the square shape overlapping each other (as can be seen in the plot above). I cannot figure out why this is happening, but I would like the legend for `'HQ'` and `'LQ'` to reflect the proper shapes (square and triangle respectively).

The data to reproduce this are as follows:

```
require('data.table') # not sure if this is necessary, but just in case
> dput(data)
structure(list(month = structure(c(15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 
14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 
15279, 15340, 15400, 15492, 15553, 15126, 15371, 15522, 15309, 
15461, 15431), class = "Date"), high_q = c(0.0543422228029794, 
0.0538360449888788, 0.0542576885322506, 0.0563374158664627, 0.051832022940258, 
0.0511098243497093, 0.0516824037401732, 0.0508625794149931, 0.0508129898329969, 
0.0522992472796989, 0.0534593224542862, 0.053658852482904, 0.0527596522451362, 
0.0536379383601105, 0.0537250634604839, 0.053270060949945, 0.0551497117304649, 
0.05453991405068, 0.0514309991121669, 0.0528033236299854, 0.0556533741364405, 
0.0575938660077188, 0.0536383751376219, 0.0540292765156109), 
    low_q = c(0.150651382807563, 0.151678928161841, 0.152412405006079, 
    0.154346297912537, 0.148160747764117, 0.145711811622833, 
    0.146989273508668, 0.145807363651857, 0.146620317131406, 
    0.152241594600521, 0.154136431058451, 0.151915467273669, 
    0.151421212763034, 0.152599450134152, 0.149039642113193, 
    0.14629263019443, 0.149301086354786, 0.150944206416902, 0.148813843877971, 
    0.148000221284121, 0.152041900070419, 0.152751500401794, 
    0.147225953877478, 0.146177782497413)), .Names = c("month", 
"high_q", "low_q"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: I got an error reading your data. You may need to remove the `,.internal.selfref = ... ` bit.

Comment: It's because you are _setting_ lots of aesthetics that you should probably be _mapping_. Since you only have two series, you should be mapping both color and shape. Mapping aesthetics is how ggplot "figures out" what's supposed to go in the legend.

Comment: @tospig Got it, it's removed now. Hopefully that works.

Comment: @ joran Many thanks for your comment. As I'm relatively new to ggplot, I'm wondering if you might explain in more detail what you mean or provide an example of some code which does something similar but maps rather than sets the aesthetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that `ggplot2` prefers data in `long` format, so I always `melt` my data first:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(data, id.vars=c("month"))
```

You can then plot it using:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=month, y=value, group=variable)) +
  geom_line(color="gray40") + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=variable), colour="skyblue4") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0, 2)) +
  theme_bw()
```

This gives you the the basis of what you're after, i.e. separate shapes in the legend. You can then add the additional themes as you wish.